# cannot await method group func delegate

Tags: c#, async-await

I have a func delegate that is defined as follows,

```
   public enum RunEndStatus
    {
        Success
    }
    public class classA
    {
        Func<object, RunEndStatus> ProcessCalibrationRun { get; set; }
    }
```

Now in an other class lets say classB I am doing something like this,

```
public class ClassB
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        ClassA a = new ClassA();
        a.ProcessCalibrationRun = ProcessCalibrationRun;//This is just fine. It won't complain here.
    }
    public RunEndStatus ProcessCalibrationRun(object obj)
    {
        //Here I have some piece of code takes so much time. To replicate it,
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
    }
}
```

When the DoSomething method is called from somewhere, the application blocks for 10 minutes.So I am trying to fix my problem as follows,

```
 public async Task<RunEndStatus> ProcessCalibrationRun(object obj)
    {
        await Task.Run(() => { Thread.Sleep(10000)});
        return RunEndStatus.Success;
    }
```

I am modifying the call as follows. But it says cannot await method group. Please help how can I await on that method.

```
 public async void DoSomething()
    {
        ClassA a = new ClassA();
        a.ProcessCalibrationRun = await ProcessCalibrationRun; //Here it complains saying cannot await method group.
    }
```

Comment: It makes it easyier to read the code if its formatted correctly

Comment: Ok Let me type it in visual studio and edit

Comment: Just add a couple of spaces where its needed, id do it, except i am extremely lazy :)

Comment: You can't convert an async method to synchronous with a `await`.  You can `await` a call to ProcessCalibrationRun - ie. `await ProcessCalibrationRun(anObject);`.  You'd have to change `classA.ProcessCalibrationRun` delegate to `Func<object, Task<RunEndStatus>>()`.

Comment: Ok instead of making that change, if I create a new thread and do that Thread.Sleep(10000) in that new thread will it not block? But at what point should I say Thread.Join();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `async` signature returns a `Task`, so your `Func` will need to as well

```
public Func<object, Task<RunEndStatus>> ProcessCalibrationRun { get; set; }
```

Meaning you will not need the `async` signature  in your `DoSomething`, which should not be `async void` anyway

```
public void DoSomething()
{
   vara = new ClassA();
   a.ProcessCalibrationRun = ProcessCalibrationRun;
}
```

Then somewhere else (perhaps in `ClassA`) you can invoke it

```
public async Task DoSomethingElse()
{
   await ProcessCalibrationRun(somethignObject);
}
```